# Getting value from edittext preference in preference screen

Tags: android, dialog, android-activity, preferencescreen, edittextpreference

I'm new to android development. I just heard about preference screen in android. So I just made one. This is just to enter name in a dialog.

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <EditTextPreference 
   android:title="Name"
   android:summary="To enter name click on Name"
   android:dialogTitle="Name Dialog"
   android:dialogMessage="Enter Your Name"
   android:key="name"/>
```

This is my created preference screen. I just need to know how can I access the entered name 'tony' in my mainactivity. I don't know the way to access the name from the dialog. Do I need to add any seperate activity for accessing the name in the name dialog. Can someone please explain it to me.

[image][image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("name", null);
```

Where `this` is a `Context` like an `Activity`.
`name` is the `key` defined in your xml file.